# how much time GCM CCS wait for an acknowledgement from an XMPP server before retrying for the same message?

Tags: android, push-notification, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have an XMPP server which receive the message from android devices through GCM. If GCM sends any message to my server and my server doesn't send any acknowledgement soon after receiving the message, how much time GCM will take to resend the same message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't send an ACK for a message, CCS resends it **the next time a new XMPP connection is established**, unless the message expires first.

Source: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#format